# Make a custom ArrayList toString() that displays contents line by line?

Tags: arrays, list, tostring, lines

I understand with toString() methods, their must be a return type, when an external method is called.

The comment block below describes what I'm trying to do.

Later on when I work with setters and getters, this knowledge will most definitely be invaluable.

---

```
import java.util.*;
public class Display_ArrayList {

static ArrayList<String> cars = new ArrayList<String>();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    cars.add("Nissan Maxima");
    cars.add("Toyota Prius");
    cars.add("Renault Clio");
    cars.add("Ford Focus");
    cars.add("Volkwagen Passat");

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("[Standard toString()]:");
    System.out.println(cars.toString());

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("[Custom toString()]:");
    System.out.println(custom_cars_toString());
}

// Array list displays the car list all on the same line
public static String getCarList() {
    return cars.toString();
}

// *************************************************************************
// I want Array list contents to be displayed on their own lines without
// commas or brackets, while at the same allowing this method to be
// retrieved by a toString() method
// *************************************************************************
// public static void getCarList() {
// for (String element : cars)
// System.out.println(element);
// }

public static String custom_cars_toString() {
    return "The cars contained are: \n" + getCarList();
}
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just make a class that extends ArrayList which overrides the toString method? Then you could make something like this:

```
public class DisplayArrayList<T> extends ArrayList {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String res = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
            res += (i == 0 ? "" : "\n") + get(i).toString();
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Then you can just put your cars in a DisplayArrayList instead of an ArrayList and then when you print that you will get them all on individual lines.

For example this:

```
DisplayArrayList<String> list = new DisplayArrayList<>();
list.add("test1");
list.add("test2");
list.add("test3");
list.add("test4");
list.add("test5");
System.out.println(list);
```

Would output this:

```
test1
test2
test3
test4
test5
```

Sorry if this doesn't do what you want to, couldn't completely figure out what you want from your post.